# Sympy defining matrix by function: TypeError

Tags: python, typeerror, sympy

I'm able to define `sympy` matrices using functions. For a specific function, I'm getting a `TypeError`.

```py
sympy.Matrix(4, 4, lambda i,j: -1^(i-j) )
```

or

```py
def c(i,j):
    return -1^(i-j)
sympy.Matrix(4, 4, c)
```

The error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-f922eb663788> in <module>
      2     return -1^(i-j)
      3 # sympy.Matrix(4, 4, c)
----> 4 sympy.Matrix(4, 4, lambda i,j: -1^(i-j) )

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/matrices/dense.py in __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    297 
    298     def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
--> 299         return cls._new(*args, **kwargs)
    300 
    301     @classmethod

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/matrices/dense.py in _new(cls, copy, *args, **kwargs)
    308             rows, cols, flat_list = args
    309         else:
--> 310             rows, cols, flat_list = cls._handle_creation_inputs(*args, **kwargs)
    311             flat_list = list(flat_list) # create a shallow copy
    312         self = object.__new__(cls)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.py in _handle_creation_inputs(cls, *args, **kwargs)
   1100                 for i in range(rows):
   1101                     flat_list.extend(
-> 1102                         [cls._sympify(op(cls._sympify(i), cls._sympify(j)))
   1103                          for j in range(cols)])
   1104 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1100                 for i in range(rows):
   1101                     flat_list.extend(
-> 1102                         [cls._sympify(op(cls._sympify(i), cls._sympify(j)))
   1103                          for j in range(cols)])
   1104 

<ipython-input-28-f922eb663788> in <lambda>(i, j)
      2     return -1^(i-j)
      3 # sympy.Matrix(4, 4, c)
----> 4 sympy.Matrix(4, 4, lambda i,j: -1^(i-j) )

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'int' and 'Zero'
```

From the error log, it seems that `i-j` is evaluated to `int` and to `Zero` (probably when `i == j`).

How do I right the function to make sure `i-j` is always evaluated to `int`?

Answer (score 0):

Forcing the result of `i-j` with a `int` cast solves the issue:

```py
sympy.Matrix(4, 4, lambda i,j: -1^int(i-j) )
```

or

```py
def c(i,j):
    return -1^int(i-j)
sympy.Matrix(4, 4, c)
```

The result is:

[image]